# How to put a couple modules together in spring hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I've developed a service module in Spring/Hibernate that I've tested on it's own. A client web main module will call this service module. Both modules use the same database using separate tables except for one table used commonly.

I've added org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter to my web.xml (but now removed it) to maintain a hibernate session across the modules. I did that to get rid of spring injection problems across the two contexts.

Following blog.codehangover.com/load-multiple-contexts-into-spring and

```
  after dropping OpenSessionInViewFilter I have this in web.xml:

        <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/spring/applicationContext.xml 
        classpath:appContextJmsSendMod.xml classpath:/spring 
          /hibernateContext.xml</param-value>
             </context-param>

       the client module applicationContext.xml has
                <context:component-scan base-package="project.controller"/>
         <context:component-scan base-package="project.dao"/>
         <context:component-scan base-package="project.entity"/>
         <context:component-scan base-package="project.service"/>

              <mvc:annotation-driven />

           <bean id="jmsSender" class="project.msg.SendJmsFromDbReferral" 
                 p:activated="true" />
            etc ...

         the hibernateContext.xml file has:

             <bean id="sessionFactory" 
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
               <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
               <property name="mappingLocations">
                <list>
                <value>classpath*:hbm/Invoice.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>classpath*:hbm/LineItem.hbm.xml</value>
                 etc...
                </list>
               </property> 
               <property name="hibernateProperties">
               <props>
               <prop 
                 key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop>
                </props>
                </property>
              </bean>

           and appContextJmsSendMod.xml  has 

                <context:component-scan base-package="project.msg"/>   

                <bean id="sessionFactoryJmsMod" 
                  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
                     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceJmsMod"/>
                  <property name="packagesToScan" value="project.msg"/>
                  <property name="hibernateProperties">
                    etc..


      with this my service module project.msg.SendJmsFromDbReferral gets a no session within it as it tries to execute a hibernate dao. I get the same no session if I try the second approach in the blog and import my second app context.
```

Comment: I didn't get your question, do you have two services? Does each one has an individual sessionFactory? Do both services exist in a single web-application?

Comment: After doing some reading today I think I've misunderstood how one should put together client and service modules in Spring/hibernate. I'm going to try the method here tomorrow with web.xml contextConfigLocation: http://blog.codehangover.com/load-multiple-contexts-into-spring/ which means I should take out OpenSessionInViewFilter and, as I understand, get two separate sessions from two separate application contexts.

Comment: So someone else developed a module in xml based spring that does UI and rest web services with hibernate db. I developed and tested a separate module (for jaxb marshalling) which also used the same database but mostly other tables. I want his module to call mine. So two separate app contexts each with a sessionFactory. One referencing a list of hibernate tables in xml while the other scans annotations. My problem has been putting them together.

Comment: Earlier I tried both web.xml contextConfigLocation and the app context import that http://blog.codehangover.com/load-multiple-contexts-into-spring/ mentions but I think my OpenSessionInViewFilter is causing problems (since it's supposed to maintain session rather than drop and change them).

Comment: Ha no luck I get no session in the first hibernate call in my service module : org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
 org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
 org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:941)